# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I'm trying to iterate through a DataFrame with a for loop but I'm getting this error:

"ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous."

My dataframe is:
[image: Dataframe]

And I would like to iterate through "Plataforma " and "Soporte" to replace 'Soporte' values.
I am using this:

```
for index, row in informe.iterrows():

    if informe.loc[index, 'Plataforma'] == 'Taboola':
        informe['Soporte'].str.replace('performance-prospecting_tconvergentes', 'Prospecting_Taboola_tconvergentes')
        informe['Soporte'].str.replace('performance-prospecting_tmoviles', 'Prospecting_Taboola_tmoviles')
        informe['Soporte'].str.replace('performance-prospecting', 'Prospecting_Taboola')

    elif informe.loc[index, 'Plataforma'] == 'Yahoo':
        informe['Soporte'].str.replace('performance-prospecting_tconvergentes', 'Prospecting_Yahoo_tconvergentes')
        informe['Soporte'].str.replace('performance-prospecting_tmoviles', 'Prospecting_Yahoo_tmoviles')
        informe['Soporte'].str.replace('performance-prospecting', 'Prospecting_Yahoo')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `iterrows` is one of slowiest iterating solution in pandas, better is avoid it, check [this answer by pandas developer Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-pandas-iterrows-have-performance-issues/24871316#24871316).

So you can create dictionaries for replacement, filter rows by mask with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
d1= {'performance-prospecting_tconvergentes': 'Prospecting_Taboola_tconvergentes',
     'performance-prospecting_tmoviles': 'Prospecting_Taboola_tmoviles',
     'performance-prospecting': 'Prospecting_Taboola'}

d2 = {'performance-prospecting_tconvergentes': 'Prospecting_Yahoo_tconvergentes',
      'performance-prospecting_tmoviles': 'Prospecting_Yahoo_tmoviles',
      'performance-prospecting':'Prospecting_Yahoo'}


m1 = informe['Plataforma'] == 'Taboola'
m2 = informe['Plataforma'] == 'Yahoo'

informe.loc[m1, 'Soporte'] = informe.loc[m1, 'Soporte'].replace(d1)
informe.loc[m2, 'Soporte'] = informe.loc[m2, 'Soporte'].replace(d2)
```